# When I ref bubble sort method and try to print only gives one value?

Tags: c#

**I am fetching the Grade of the Students. I am trying to fetch Student Grades in sorted order. But when i printed the `testgrade` variable its just showing only one record at the end.**

```
namespace EX4_GradesMethod
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int namelength;
            string names;
            double grade, max, min, testgradeaverage;

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount of names you wish to enter: ");
            namelength = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            string[] name = new string[namelength];
            double[] testgrades = new double[namelength];

            for (int i = 0; i < testgrades.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the names of each student");
                names = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                name[i] += names; 
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the final grade for " + name[i]);
                grade = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                testgrades[i] += grade;          
            }
            max = testgrades.Max();
            min = testgrades.Min();
            testgradeaverage = testgrades.Average();

            Console.WriteLine("The highest grade is: " + max);
            Console.WriteLine("The Lowest Grade is:" + min);

            Console.WriteLine("The class average is: " + testgradeaverage);

            for ( int k = 0; k < namelength - namelength + 1; k++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(testgrades[k]);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        public static void sorted(ref double [] testgrades)
        {
            double temp = 0;
            for (int write = 0; write < testgrades .Length; write++)
            {
                for (int sort = 0; sort < testgrades.Length - 1; sort++)
                {
                    if (testgrades [sort] > testgrades [sort + 1])
                    {
                        temp = testgrades[sort + 1];
                        testgrades [sort + 1] = testgrades [sort];
                        testgrades [sort] = temp;
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for ( int k = 0; k < namelength - namelength + 1; k++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(testgrades[k]);
        }? x-x+1? = 1? then you should expect only 1 record only

Comment: that worked it was something I overlooked thank you

Comment: changed it to just name length and it worked thanks again